# JavaScript - vertically center an <option> relatively to the <select>

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following HTML code and JavaScript... when the option in the select is selected it is suppose to be centered, but the JavaScript doesn't seem to be working.

I am not familiar with JavaScript so excuse me asking. Though it seems to work [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BA39h/1/).

```
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 2</title>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >

$('#tertiary_category_select').on('change', function(){
    var n = this.getAttribute('size'),
        i = this.selectedIndex,
        l = this.options.length;
    this.selectedIndex = Math.min(l-1,i+n/2|0);
    this.selectedIndex = Math.max(0,i+1-n/2|0);
    this.selectedIndex = i;
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<select id="tertiary_category_select" name="tertiary_category_select" size="5">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
</select>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: And the scripts `src` url is wrong, I believe.

Comment: Per @nevermind link, you can see this if you change the jsfiddle to 'No wrap - in <head>' then it wont work.

Comment: So should I change - $('tertiary_category_select').on('change', function(){ to $('tertiary_category_select').ready('change', function(){

Comment: @user3173207, no you should wrap code you got with this: $( document ).ready(function() {
//put code here!!!
});

Comment: As I told you earlier. I am not familiar with jquery. So I am bit stuck. I am trying to fiddle around but to no avail :-(

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BA39h/2/

Answer (score 0):

`<option>` elements are not like other HTML tags. They are rendered by the operating system, not by the browser. They are controls, not elements. The ability to style these are quite limited. Being able to vertically-center them is not possible.

You may want to consider a script-based alternative, which can be styled, such as [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns).

Comment: Yes, you are right, but code is working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/BA39h/1/ Problem is described/explained in comments above. :)

Comment: That's not quite the same thing, but I get what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach event handlers to DOM elements only after this element was generated.

To do this add the script just before the closing body tag or wrap the code in an event listener that listens for when the DOM is "ready".

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('#tertiary_category_select').on('change', function(){
    var n = this.getAttribute('size'),
        i = this.selectedIndex,
        l = this.options.length;
    this.selectedIndex = Math.min(l-1,i+n/2|0);
    this.selectedIndex = Math.max(0,i+1-n/2|0);
    this.selectedIndex = i;
});

});
```